# Get Clicked Row of GridView

Tags: c#, silverlight, row, telerik-grid

I have an `RadGridView` and a `HyperLink` button attached to each row. I want to get the value of column `ID` on Hyperlink's `Click` event. I tried this but got `NullReferenceException` because `SelectedItem` contains null.

```
private void OnGetDetailsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail();
   Product product = this.grdProductGrid.SelectedItem as Product;
   productDetail.ProductId = product.ProductID
}
```

Xaml for `RadGridView`

```
<telerik:RadGridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Height="278" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                          Width="1220" 
                          Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                          Name="grdProductGrid"
                          ColumnWidth="*"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="ID" 
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductID}" 
                                                Header="ID" 
                                                IsReadOnly="True" 
                                                IsVisible="False"/>


                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="Name" 
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                                                Header="Name" 
                                                IsReadOnly="True" />

                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="Description" 
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" 
                                                Header="Description" 
                                                IsReadOnly="True" />


                    <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Details" Width="*">
                        <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <HyperlinkButton Content="Details" 
                                                     Tag="Hyperlinkbutton" 
                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                     Click="OnGetDetailsClick"/> 
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn>
                  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Whats wrong with my code? How can I access the row on `Click` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CommandParameter` to pass a `Product` to the click event

```
  <HyperlinkButton Content="Details" 
    Tag="Hyperlinkbutton" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
   Click="OnGetDetailsClick" CommandParameter={Binding .}/>
```

and in your code behind you have

```
Product product=((Product)((HyperlinkButton)sender).CommandParameter)
```

Comment: {Binding .} means binding to the current object. If your current Object is an instance of a product, then you can bind to that. however, you can bind to a property of your instance as well. like {Binding ProductID} in that case the parameter passed to click event is ProductID not the Product instance itself

Comment: The `CommandParameter` makes it so easy to access stuff. Thanks man!